# file_get_contents() works on Local but not on server

Tags: php, laravel

I have finished my client project with laravel and after  many  test  in local all works good , but after hosting project to serve show this error :

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 (View: /htdocs/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

Please help me .

Comment: The error message is clear. Check your server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

allow_url_fopen is disabled (for good reason) on most productions servers. You shouldn't use it for getting files over URL. Use CURL fo it instead